# Allow any user to connect to postgres with full permissions?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, vagrant

I love `postgres.app`. It makes it really simple to develop against postgres. I'm configuring a vagrant setup so some of my other developer friends can easily use postgres, however I'd like to enable the same behavior of `postgres.app`, namely I'd like them to be able to connect using `localhost` and without having to have a username or password specified. I know it's gotta be possible, but I haven't figured out how yet. Any ideas?

Worst case I can create a super user, since I know the username of vagrant boxes, but if you have any ideas, I'd love to hear 'em.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can automatically install local instance of PostgreSQL server and preconfigure [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file to have `trust` entries like this:

```
# Allow any user on the local system to connect to any database
# with any database user name using Unix-domain sockets
# (the default for local connections):
# TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS       METHOD
local  all      all                trust
# The same using local loopback TCP/IP connections:
host   all      all  127.0.0.1/32  trust
```

Comment: Note to OP: When using `trust` you must still `CREATE USER` the PostgreSQL user they connect to. PostgreSQL doesn't (currently) support auto-creating users or databases on first connection. Of course, you can all share one user account.